# List items in separate rows

Tags: c#, listview

I'm still fairly new at using `ListView`s so this may seem like an elementary question, but how exactly would I go about listing one item per row?

For example, my code which displays all the files from a folder looks like this:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Properties.Settings.Default.workspace + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "system" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "app");
foreach (string file in files)
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(fileName);

    item.Tag = file;

    listView1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

In turn the output looks like this:

```
SomeFile1 SomeFile2 SomeFile3 SomeFile4

SomeFile5 SOmeFile6 SOmeFile 7 SomeFile 8
```

My goal is to try to get it to look like this:

```
someFile 1

SomeFile 2

SomeFile 3

...
```

I know it has something to do with how I added the items, but I'm still not too sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `listView1.View= View.List` , it should work.

By default it's set to `LargeIcon`.

You can set this property in constructor or by properties menu.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response...I can't believe I didn't see that, although it turns out that I needed to just change the properties to "tile" that solved it. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Praveen, but  I just figured out that I needed to change the list view to tile, that solved it.